# How to fetch all the current messages present in Kafka topic through Spring Boot Application

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

**Requirement**: To filter kafka topic data on the basis of an id.
I need to create an API and on the basis of the input passed, I have to filter out the data from the messages present in the Kafka topic at that point of time.

**Example**: Below are the records present in Topic

```
{"id" : "1" ,"name" : "ABC", dept: "Computer"}
{"id" : "1" ,"name" : "FGH", dept: "Mechanical"}
```

So if I hit an API "/getAllMessages" I should get all the records present in the topic.

**PS.** - We are not saving Kafka messages in any Database.

Can anyone please help me resolve.

Comment: Lots of questions you need to answer here... Why would you have two messages with the same ID and different data? Should those override each other in the response? What if there are thousands of messages? How do you plan on dealing with HTTP client timeouts? How do you know when to actually "return" if there are still data being produced? Ideally, You should instead build a KTable and query _that_, not the topic itself

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer... I agree to the points you have mentioned and such problems may definitely occur with huge amount of data.
I will try to implement KTable...

Comment: This blog series might help - https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/09/stream-processing-with-spring-cloud-stream-and-apache-kafka-streams-part-6-state-stores-and-interactive-queries

Comment: Alternatively, people have already built solutions that (mostly) do all this for you - https://www.azkarrastreams.io/